# How can we know that two equations, e.g., $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 2x + 1$ describe the same geometrical object?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, curves, plane-curves

The typical procedure to prove that these two can describe the same object seems to me to show that $f(x) + x + 1 = g(x)$. What isn't so clear to me, is why exactly does this constitute a proof that the graph of these two functions correspond to the same object? In other words, how come $h(f(x)) = g(x)$ guarantees that the equality in algebra also holds in geometry?

There seems to me to be a tremendous difference between algebra, where an equation constitutes equality, and geometry, where we must imagine we can superpose two objects in other to say they are equal. So, for instance, even if $h(f(x)) = g(x)$, wouldn't it be possible that, now no longer speaking of algebra but of geometry, a good enough zoom would show us that actually, h(f(x)) is actually slightly tilted in comparison to g(x)? Somehow, we know that because, $h(f(x)) = g(x)$, this isn't the case, but why?

Comment: One could verify $f''(x) = g''(x) = 0$ for all $x$ so that both graphs are straight ($0$ convexity) lines.

Comment: @VIVID right, but the question of geometry and algebra is left intact, no? We're depending on the jump from algebra to geometry, i.e. the guarantee that $f''(x)$ actually corresponds to a significant geometrical characteristic of a line, its curve. I'm trying to figure out what exactly guarantees this jump from algebra to geometry.

Comment: In other words, this sounds a bit weird, but what if, indeed, $f''(x) = g''(x) = 0$, so the equality holds algebraically, but geometrically, when I superpose the two lines, I make a mistake and leave one of the lines slightly tilted, so I haven't actually achieved geometrical equality, only algebraic equality. I'm trying to figure out, what exactly is it that prevents me from making this mistake of leaving one of the lines slightly tilted, so as to be able to say: well, even if you make this mistake, the geometric equality holds.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "same geometrical object". The graphs are different subsets of the plane. Is the line $y = x$ the "same geometrical object" as the line $y = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you define "same object"? Those functions are different functions, they are not the same. In geometry we often like to say that two shapes are the "same object" or congruent if we can transform one into the other solely by (proper) rotations and translations. Sometimes we also allow reflections and stretches.

The function $f$ is composed of the set of pairs of points $\{(x,x)\}$ and the function $g$ is composed of the set of the pairs of points $\{(x,2x+1)\}.$ We can translate the points in $g:$
$$T_{y-1}(\{(x,2x+1)\}) = \{(x,2x)\}$$
Then we can rotate by the appropriate angle:
$$R_\theta (T_{y-1}(\{(x,2x+1)\}) = R_\theta (\{x,2x\}) = \{(x,x)\}$$

So the sets are equivalent up to a translation and rotation. I'm skipping over details here, but this is the gist.

Comment: thank you, this makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

One interpretation of "same geometrical object" is "isometric".

Let $F$ be the graph of $f$ and $G$ be the graph of $g$.

Then $\phi: F \to G$ given by $\phi(x,x) = \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt5},2\frac{x}{\sqrt5}+1\right)$ is an isometry.

$F$ is clearly isometric to $\mathbb R$. But the natural parametrization of $G$ given by $t \mapsto (t,2t+1)$ is not an isometry because the derivative has norm $\sqrt 5$, hence the scaling above.

Comment: this answer is just as good as the other one, thank you!